# Multiline textview getting cut off in height

Tags: android, layout, textview

I have a `TextView` next to an `ImageButton` in a horizontal `LinearLayout` which is then wrapped in a vertical `LinearLayout`. To get the button to show up I had to set a `layout_weight` on the text view and button with the button being the stronger of the two. However this seems to make the button decide the height of both of them, even if the text needs to be higher. Is there any way to get around this?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/medium_font"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="A long text that wraps correctly but then gets cut off"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="@string/share_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/share_button"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_menu_share_holo_dark"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:id="@+id/distances_parent">
        <Spinner
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/distance_labels"
            android:id="@+id/distances" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="@color/back_end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ...
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Cut off text]

As you can see the button decides the height, not the text as should be.

This is what I want it to look like:

[image: Text not cut off]

Comment: Instead of LinearLayout use can use RelativeLayout to make this possible. Please provide your expected output as image[drawing].

Comment: I have edited the post with what I want it to look like.

Comment: You have a pretty complicated layout. I suggest stripping it down and seeing if you can get just the core part - as shown in your screen shots - to work properly. You might also try the XML attribute android:measureWithLargestChild in your 2nd LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code.

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/share_button"
        android:text="A long text that wraps correctly but then gets cut off"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/medium_font"" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/share_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="imagebutton"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_menu_share_holo_dark"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/distances"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:entries="@array/distance_labels" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If your TextView contains more text. The TextView's height will increase according to that ImageButton and spinner will adjust. Try and check. I hope it will help you. All the best.

Comment: I used this solution, not exactly to the letter but the gist of it. Not only does it solve the problem, it also simplifies the layout which was a bit complicated (as some pointed out). @Abtin Gramian has a similar answer I could have choosen as well but this was first.

Comment: Thanks. All the best. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to help without knowing how your entire view looks.  Is this filling the entire screen or is it nested in another layout? Then we can tell what height the topmost layout in this particular layout is matching since you are using `match_parent` rather than a specific value.

You needed to set the `layout_weight` on the text view because you have the width set as `0dp` rather than `wrap_content`.  Those go hand in hand. The `0dp`, `weightSum`, and `layout_weight` attributes are used to split up the remaining empty space between a set of elements within a `LinearLayout`.

Your `Spinner` widget is nested inside a `LinearLayout` which is unnecessary because the entire view is already in a vertical `LinearLayout` so the spinner will appear below the text and image already. You want to keep your layout as shallow as possible to optimize for performance.

I'm also not sure why you are using the `Space` widget rather than setting padding, margin, or using alignment attributes.

If you did want to handle splitting the empty space then use this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="A long text that wraps correctly but then gets cut off"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/share_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/text_view"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_menu_share_holo_dark"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/distances"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_view"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

But it looks like you can use a `RelativeLayout` here.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="A long text that wraps correctly but then gets cut off"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/share_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/text_view"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_menu_share_holo_dark"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/distances"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_view"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that the reason I had the spinner inside a linear layout was so I could add the background I wanted to it. If you add the background directly to the spinner the little down-arrow disappears for some reason. Although a linear layout is probably not the best, so I've changed it to a frame layout instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/medium_font"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="A long text that wraps correctly but then gets cut off"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

You just need to set layout_height ="According your need " That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code in my xml and working perfect.
i just converted frame layout, linear layout and space width to match_parent
Note: i have just removed unnecessry layouts and images

but i will sugest to use Relative layout for that purpose
because that all work can be done in single hirarchy level
The more you will put deeper hirarchi levels of layout the more time screen will take to load the view 
it is good practice if we can do it in minimal levels

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="A long text that wrapdasdsd dff f df df sdf asdf sdf sadf dsf sdf sdaf adsf adsf sdf sdaf sdf sdf sadf sadf sdf sd fsdf sadf asdf sdaf sdaf sf saf asf dsf sadf sdf sdaf sdf as df dfs correctly but then gets cut off"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/share_button"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing all it wrong.if you are using layout_weight then u need to set layout_width of textView and ImageButton both of them to be zero dp.Assign them as per ur requirement.like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="A long text that wraps correctly but then gets cut off"
    android:textSize="@dimen/medium_font"
    android:layout_weight="9"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_menu_share_holo_dark">
```

you can choose the watever size for layout height.But dont make any changes to layout width.If this works let me know in comment section